# Click and Drag Camera Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm struggling to change the axis from X and Y axis to X and Z axis. Can someone help me?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraDragMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float panSpeed = 10f;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) // right mouse button
        {
            var newPosition = new Vector3();
            newPosition.x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * panSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            newPosition.y = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * panSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            // translates to the opposite direction of mouse position.
            transform.Translate(-newPosition);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `newPosition.z = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * panSpeed * Time.deltaTime;` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean move along the X and Z axis as opposed to X and Y (and not both at once), you could do this instead of your current movement.

```
newPosition.x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * panSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
newPosition.z = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * panSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
```

In this, I am literally just changing the Z value of the [Vector3](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html). It may be worth looking into the [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/) if you don't know how stuff like this works.